# How to do UI testing for calling and receving a phone call from a Particular Number in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcuitest, xcuielement

I am trying to do UI testing for making a phone call and receiving call but the test case is failing But I tried all XCUIElementTypeQueryProvider still is Not working.

```
func testPhoneCall() {
    let Button = app.buttons["Call"]
    XCTAssertTrue(Button.exists)
    Button.tap()
    sleep(2)
    
    let cancelButton = app.alerts["Cancel"]
    XCTAssertTrue(cancelButton.exists)
    cancelButton.tap()
    sleep(2)
    
    let callButton = app.popUpButtons["Call"]
    XCTAssertTrue(callButton.exists)
    callButton.tap()
    sleep(5)
}
```

This is the code what I tried But when I try to run this test case it is failing

```
@IBAction func callButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        callNumber(phoneNumber:"")
}
private func callNumber(phoneNumber:String) {
    if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "telprompt://\(+9535965654)") {
        let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
        if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
            application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code which I wrote in view controller. can any one help me to write UItestcase for this code? Thank you

Comment: The prompt dialog is presented by the operating system,  not your app, so you won't find the dialog or the buttons in your view

Comment: You can unit test `callButtonClicked(phoneNumber:)`. The tests will be super-fast and precise. (This will require defining a protocol so that your tests can provide their own fake version of `UIApplication`.)